# onchange runnning, but select value not changing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with an onchange function.

**Problem** - The function runs, but after it runs, the select value itself does not change (i.e. when you click the dropdown menu and click an option, it does not change to that option being selected).

I have tried to find some solutions, but they are mostly either the select value not changing at all, or onclick being used instead of onchange. If i do not have the function run, however, it works perfectly fine.

This is the HTML portion, i excluded the javascript and CSS portion from the post as it would take up the entire page

```
<select id="calcType1" oninput="checkShow('enter1',this)">
    <option value="val">Entered Value</option>
    <option value="saveVal">Saved Value</option>
    <option value="saveVal2">Saved Value 2</option>
    <option value="saveVal3">Saved Value 3</option>
</select>
<div class="noBreak shown" id="enter1">
    <input id="calcValue1" class="number"> ±
    <input id="calcUnc1" class="number">
</div>
```

Jsfiddle demonstration: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkdyze8o/1/)

Comment: can you explain your requirement in short..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the assignment (=) operator instead of the boolean equality (== or ===) operator. The following line of code in your `checkShow` function is to blame:

```
if (dropdown.value = "val") {
```

It should actually read something closer to the following:

```
if (dropdown.value == "val") {
```

This is causing the value of the dropdown to be assigned the value "val" instead of checking that it is equal to "val".

I have updated the snippet

http://jsfiddle.net/vkdyze8o/13/